# How to have "margin:auto" and "margin-left:offset" working together?

Tags: css

I have a container on my [test site](http://asha.onalllevels.com/specials):

```
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Then I added the left vertical menu and on some small screens that menu is not fully visible.
*Like my old laptop :-)*

I want to keep the `margin:auto` setting in place but I want to move the whole `#container` a little bit to the right.

#### Could it be done some how?

I have tried `#container {margin-left:10px;}`, but to no avail.

Comment: Is there some specific reason why the left menu must stay in the header div

Comment: no there is no specific reason for that. I wanted the menu to be on left side. How it is done really doesn't matter. I am happy to implement any better way if you have any suggestion.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Playing with firebug, it's good to use:

```
#container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 position:relative;
 left:10px;
}
```

Hope it solves...

Comment: not only any extra markup but it is also so elegant (at least for me :-)

Comment: It's all about the "love" for the code :) Tks nickf and Radek, clad I could help!

Comment: Gorgeous solution — clean and very clear. This is why I love CSS.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be the case anymore, at least not in chrome... the left position does not re-distribute the margins with the remaining space but instead just pushes the container out of the screen with a right position of negative whatever you add to the left... explicitly giving the right position a value of 0 does nothing

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach would be to introduce another element (or style another element if it's already available). Thus, you might have:

```
<div style="margin-left: 10px;">
   <div id="container" style="margin: auto;">...</div>
</div>
```

That way the centering is being done within a container div that's already got the appropriate left-hand padding.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap your `#container` div in another div with *double* the left margin, that will work.

```
  #wrap {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .centre { /* this would be your #container */
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #f00;
  }
  #wrap .centre {
    background-color: #00f;
  }
```

The HTML:

```
  <div class="centre"></div>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div class="centre"></div>
  </div>
```

http://jsbin.com/emogu3